# JRuby lock table using mysql not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, locking, jruby

I have 2 server one is running Windows Tomcat using JRuby language the other one is Running in linux ruby language, both of them use mysql database the problem is in linux using lock(ex. :lock => true or lock(true)) is working but in Windows Tomcat it doesn't work

Looking at the log file both server generate the same sql statement
"[1m[36mSequence Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mselect * from sequences where sequence_key = 'business_account_no80012015' for update[0m"

Is there some problem in JRuby that prevent locking happens?or in Tomcat?